How to have full autorotation with reverse portrait on phones?
In my experience, I can have a 360 degree autorotation only on tabs and not on phones. On phone, I can not set up reverse portrait mode.
Some apps state that it is possible, my experiences are bad with them (they don't work et all, or don't work on locked screen or similars).
Can I somehow set up a full 360 degree autorotation on phone? I have root if it is really needed.

Even on some tablets full 360 rotation is not possible, e.g. I know that on Lenovo Tab M9 reverse portrait mode is not possible. I agree with you that this is a totally stupid restriction...

About 10 years ago I have found a paid app named "ultimate rotation control", which could do this wonder. Today I use an app named "control screen orientation". It seems working, except that I would expect a much more fast reaction to the gravity sensors and I want the complete exempt of app killing.

Somewhere I have seen some system configuration thing requiring root. But I can not find it any more.
